# Redux Toolkit - do not send request when query param is invalid

Tags: redux-toolkit

I've checked the redux toolkit docs and don't see an example of this typical use case: do not send the request of the query has an invalid param.

For example, a get request to endpoint /categories/{name} requires a name value. If name does not have a value, then the request should not be made.

```
const baseQuery = fetchBaseQuery({
  baseUrl: Constants.PATHWAY_API_URL
});

export const pathwayApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'pathwayApi',
  baseQuery: baseQueryWithReAuth,
  endpoints: builder => ({
    getSubCategories: builder.query({
      // NETWORK REQUEST SHOULD NOT BE MADE IF "name" param is falsy
      query: name => `${Constants.PATHWAY_API.CATEGORIES_PATH_NAME}/${name}`,
    }),
  }),
});
```

I want to add this type of param validation to all my queries that require a param value or values. What's the recommended approach / pattern for handling this validation at the createApi (or possibly fetchBaseQuery) layer?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can actually `throw` an error in your `query` function.

```
export const pathwayApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: "pathwayApi",
  baseQuery: baseQueryWithReAuth,
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getSubCategories: builder.query({
      // NETWORK REQUEST SHOULD NOT BE MADE IF "name" param is falsy
      query: (name) => {
        if (!name) {
          throw new Error("Category name is required.");
        }
        return `${Constants.PATHWAY_API.CATEGORIES_PATH_NAME}/${name}`;
      }
    })
  })
});
```

When this happens, your hook will have `isError: true`  but no network request will be made.  The `error` property of your hook will be a `SerializedError` object with properties `name`, `message` and `stack`, which you can use to display the error in your UI.

This is the same type of error object that you get if you have a `TypeError` somewhere in your code.  Note that JavaScript errors will have `error.message` while API errors (`FetchBaseQueryError`) will have `error.error`.

```
const Category = ({ name }) => {
  const { data, error, isError } = useGetSubCategoriesQuery(name);

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>Name: "{name}"</h3>
      {isError && (
          <div>{error?.error ?? error?.message}</div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

[CodeSandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/rtk-query-skip-requests-mo5pt?file=/src/api.ts)

Comment: Thanks for the excellent answer and code sample showing the FetchBaseQueryError vs. the JS Error! Not sure why a clear example like this isn't part of RTK docs, but this is exactly the kind of example and explanation I was looking for.

Comment: Is there a way for it to return an error in the same format of `FetchBaseQueryError` ( with the `error` prop ) ?

Comment: @LoyalPotato That's an interesting question.  I don't think that the `query` property can `return { error }`, but the `queryFn` property can.  It would be something like `queryFn: async (args: Args, api: BaseQueryApi, extraOptions: {}, fetchWithBQ: BaseQuery) => { if (!name) { return { error: { status: 422, data: "Category name is required." } } } const result = await fetchWithBQ(`${Constants.PATHWAY_API.CATEGORIES_PATH_NAME}/${name}`, api, extraArgs); return result as { data: YourDataType }; }`

Comment: Ohhh ok. I thought about it maybe being possible with the `queryFn` because it receives the `fetchWithBQ` as an argument. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I found an easy way to abort **RTKs Queries Executions** using Conditional Fetching at the top level, passing by a param called **skip** in the hook call itself. Like described here:

https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/conditional-fetching

Example:

```
const { data: metaData } = useGetMetaDataQuery(
   { reportId },
   { skip: !reportId /* <- Here is the solution  */ },
);
```